# Is the design matrix in a panel regression model a tensor?

Tags: panel-data, notation, tensor

In a panel regression model of the form
$$Y_{it} = \mathbf{X}_{it} \pmb{\beta} + \epsilon_{it}$$
where

- $Y_{it}$ is the dependent variable for unit $i$ at time $t$
- $\mathbf{X}_{it}$ is a vector of $K$ predictor variables (i.e.
  $\mathbf{X}_{it} = \begin{bmatrix} X_{1,it} & X_{2,it} & \dots &
     X_{K,it} \end{bmatrix}^\top$) for unit $i$ at time $t$
- $\pmb{\beta}$ is a vector of $K$ coefficients
- $\epsilon_{it}$ is the error term
- $i \in \{1, 2, \dots, N\}$ is the unit index
- $t \in \{1, 2, \dots, T\}$ is the time index
- $k \in \{1, 2, \dots, K\}$ is the predictor index

My question concerns the 'nature' of the object $\mathbf{X}_{it}$ (often referred to as the design matrix). Since $\mathbf{X}_{it}$ is a $K \times 1$ dimensional *vector* at the $it$-level (or a scalar at the $kit$-level, $X_{kit}$), can $\mathbf{X}$ (without subscripts) be thought of as a *tensor* of dimensions $K \times N \times T$?

Comment: It could be, but it is more common to stack the matrices across the third dimension of the data cube to obtain a two-dimensional matrix.

Comment: @RichardHardy, what do you mean by "stack"? Should I imagine this as each element of that resulting two-dimensional matrix being a vector?

Comment: No. You can stack the columns of a matrix to obtain one long column, thus reducing the dimension by 1. Similarly, you can stack the "layers" of a cube (matrices) on top of each other to obtain one tall matrix, thus reducing the dimension by 1.

Comment: You could call it as representation of a tensor in certain basis, but what will that give you? Tensor formalism becomes useful when you start combining vectors using tensor product. It can be very useful once you start considering how transformations of the underlying component vectors get represented in terms of transformations acting on tensor as a whole. Otherwise it is simply another word for multi-dimensional array

Answer (score 0):

It could be, but it is more common to stack the matrices across the third dimension of the data cube to obtain a two-dimensional matrix. What do I mean by that? You can stack the columns of a matrix to obtain one long column, thus reducing the dimension by 1. Similarly, you can stack the "layers" of a cube (matrices) on top of each other to obtain one tall matrix, thus reducing the dimension by 1.